# JavaScript will post/work well in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. Works funny in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter, cross-browser

Disclaimer: I'm new to web development.

I'm posting information from a CodeIgniter based form using jQuery, and the form posts well in Chrome and Firefox with proper current page reload, it will post in Opera but requires a manual refresh, and it won't post at all in Safari. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help!

Planner.js

```
$(function() {

    $('.event_list li').click( function(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
        $('#update_view_content').load('http://example.com/user/planner/update/'+this.id,function() {
            $('#myModal').reveal();
        });
    });

    $('#updateForm').live('submit', function() {
        var data = $('#updateForm').serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url, data);
        location.reload();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
$.post(url, data, function() {
    document.location.reload();
});
```